# How to fix Error: The trait BorshSerialize is not implemented for Pubkey

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

I am using OSX with the following packages:

- `Anchor CLI 0.28.0`
- `Rust       1.70.0`
- `Solana CLI 1.16.1`

To flush cache and ensure my environment is clean I have run:

`anchor clean && cargo update`

These are my project dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["metadata"] }
solana-program = "1.14.19"
mpl-token-metadata = { version = "1.12.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
```

But when I run `anchor build`, it throws multiple errors like the following:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Pubkey: BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/idl.rs:35:10
   |
35 | #[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `Pubkey`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
             &T
             ()
             (T0, T1)
             (T0, T1, T2)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
           and 81 others
```

This is the `Cargo.lock` file showing the `anchor-lang` installed dependencies:

```
[[package]]
name = "anchor-lang"
version = "0.28.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "0d2d4b20100f1310a774aba3471ef268e5c4ba4d5c28c0bbe663c2658acbc414"
dependencies = [
 "anchor-attribute-access-control",
 "anchor-attribute-account",
 "anchor-attribute-constant",
 "anchor-attribute-error",
 "anchor-attribute-event",
 "anchor-attribute-program",
 "anchor-derive-accounts",
 "anchor-derive-space",
 "arrayref",
 "base64 0.13.1",
 "bincode",
 "borsh 0.10.3",
 "bytemuck",
 "getrandom 0.2.10",
 "solana-program",
 "thiserror",
]
```

Seems like `anchor-lang` is [using a conflicting borsh version](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/v0.28.0/lang/Cargo.toml#L40) `0.10.3` when it should be using `0.9.3`. Does anyone know a workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 10):

This error is resulting from the latest `solana-program` and `mpl-token-metadata` crates being incompatible with each other due to different `borsh` versions.

The fix is simple, without making any changes to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
cargo update -p solana-zk-token-sdk --precise 1.14.19
cargo update -p borsh@0.10.3 --precise 0.9.3
```

> Seems like `anchor-lang` is [using a conflicting borsh version](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/v0.28.0/lang/Cargo.toml#L40) `0.10.3` when it should be using `0.9.3`

There is nothing conflicting there, you are able to use both `0.9` and `0.10` versions as well as `1.14` and `1.16` versions of Solana crates. Without that range specification, there would be no way of compiling crates such as `mpl-token-metadata 1.12.0` which uses `borsh 0.9.3` when the `solana-program 1.16.0` crate uses `borsh 0.10.3`.

For a longer explanation see [this comment](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2548#issuecomment-1609418578).

Comment: Thanks @acheron! Do you know if there is a way to achieve the same: `solana-zk-token-sdk==1.14.19` and `borsh@0.10.3==0.9.3` but within the  `Cargo.toml` file instead of using additional cargo update commands? For instance using `[patch.crates-io]`?

Comment: I also need an alternative, because when publishing my package on `crates.io` using `cargo publish`, same error is displayed. Is there any other way instead of using `cargo update -p ...` to make dependencies work also with `cargo publish`?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who'll be trying work on a native Solana program, here is a set-up that works...

My Solana cli suite `solana-cli 1.16.4 (src:4ce8fe76; feat:2891131721, client:SolanaLabs)`

Cargo.toml packages

```
cargo add solana-program@=1.14.19
cargo add borsh@0.9.3
cargo add borsh-derive@0.9.3
cargo add spl-token@3.3.0 --features=no-entrypoint
cargo add spl-associated-token-account@1.0.3 --features=no-entrypoint
cargo add mpl-token-metadata@1.2.5 --features=no-entrypoint
```