# Borsh dependency issue with latest versions of crates

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, borsh

I am getting this type of errors

```
the trait bound `Pubkey: BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
   --> src/system_program.rs:343:10
    |
343 | #[derive(Accounts)]
    |          ^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `Pubkey`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
              &T
              ()
              (T0, T1)
              (T0, T1, T2)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
            and 81 others
    = help: see issue #48214
    = help: add `#![feature(trivial_bounds)]` to the crate attributes to enable
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Accounts` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

this is my `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.28.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.28.0"}
#borsh = {version = "^0.10.3", features = ["const-generics"]}
mpl-token-metadata = {version = "1.12.2", features = ["no-entrypoint"]}
solana-program = {version = "1.14"}
streamflow-sdk = {version = "0.6.0", features = ["cpi"]}
```

I tried downgrading versions of solana and borsh to make `solana-program`crate and `mpl-token-metadata` compatible like said in this [Question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6997/1174)

But the streamflow-sdk requires `10.3` version of borsh.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading streamflow-sdk to 0.5.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t use anchor 28 with mpl token metadata until Metaplex updates their libraries. Downgrade to anchor 26 with Solana 1.14

Check the Anchor issues for more info