# How to fix Borsh serialize error on Anchor 0.28 when publishing crates

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-spl

Related to the [Borsh serialize error](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6991/how-to-fix-error-the-trait-borshserialize-is-not-implemented-for-pubkey) [the changes suggested by @acheron](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6997/1966) only work for running the program, but doesn't work or are ignored when publishing the crate to [crates.io](https://crates.io/).

For instance when running `cargo publish` on a program with the following dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["metadata"] }
solana-program = "=1.14.21"
```

throws many errors like this:

```
   --> src/system_program.rs:374:10
    |
374 | #[derive(Accounts)]
    |          ^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `Pubkey`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
              &T
              ()
              (T0, T1)
              (T0, T1, T2)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
            and 81 others
```

Is there any way to have that `cargo update -p borsh@0.10.3 --precise 0.9.3` applied to cargo publish?

Answer (score 2):

Try these constraints

```
anchor-lang = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["metadata"] }
solana-program = "=1.14.17"
```