# The trait `borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `T` problem

Tags: rust, cargo

Im trying to compile in rust a code to mint a candy machine directly, but after I put the dependecies in Cargo.toml it still giving me this error.

My Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "mint_project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
solana-client = "1.17.13"
solana-sdk = "1.17.13"
mpl-token-vault = "0.2.0"
error:
```

the trait bound `T: borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied
the trait `borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `T`

in: utill.rs on mpl-token-vault-0.2.0/src
Tried to change the dependencies a lot of times, tried already:

metaplex = "0.0.1"
metaplex-token-vault = "0.0.1"
metaplex-auction = "0.0.1"
others on crates.io but none of them worked, still same  borsh error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6991/how-to-fix-error-the-trait-borshserialize-is-not-implemented-for-pubkey). Do you mind checking the top answer there and reporting back if it works for you?

Answer (score 2):

`mpl-token-vault` was deprecated by Metaplex last year and is [only on solana version 1.10](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/florida/blob/main/token-vault/program/Cargo.toml). You are trying to use it with 1.17.3. I am not sure what you mean by ‘mint a candy machine directly,’ but the [Sugar cli](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/sugar) will allow you to create your own Candy Machines.